# Color Gradient (ColdFusion)

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Im trying to generate a color gradient using ColdFusion. My current code below works but it basically will only display the start color till the very last line then it will show the end color. No gradient. Just a big block of red then one line of blue. What am i not seeing wrong with my code?

```
<cfset BoxNumber = RandRange(100,1000) >

<cfset Start_Red = 255 >
<cfset Start_Green = 0 >
<cfset Start_Blue = 0 >

<cfset End_Red = 0 >
<cfset End_Green = 0 >
<cfset End_Blue = 255 >

<div id="color-band">

<cfloop index = "i" from = 0 to = #BoxNumber# >

<cfset Percent = i \ (BoxNumber - 1) >

<cfset Red = int(((End_Red - Start_Red) * Percent) + Start_Red) >
<cfset Green = int(((End_Green - Start_Green) * Percent) + Start_Green) >
<cfset Blue = int(((End_Blue - Start_Blue) * Percent) + Start_Blue) >

<div style="background-color:rgb(<cfoutput>#Red#</cfoutput>, <cfoutput>#Green#  </cfoutput>, <cfoutput>#Blue#</cfoutput>)">&nbsp;</div>

</cfloop>

</div>
```

I do know a ColdFusion server can be hard to come by sometimes so i can test the code if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<cfset Percent = i \ (BoxNumber - 1) >
...
<cfset Red = int(((End_Red - Start_Red) * Percent) + Start_Red) >
```

At least one problem is the `percent` formula returns zero (0) most of the time. So the colors never increment because the code is just adding `0` to the starting value. I think the color formula is off as well.

Unless this is a learning exercise, you might want to look for an existing function or method rather than reinventing the wheel. *(Edit:* For example, take a look at Craig's suggestion).  Otherwise, you might take a look at cflib.org for inspiration. The [fadeList](http://www.cflib.org/udf/fadeList) function shows the basic concept for generating a gradient (albeit with hex). This is not exactly right, but something along these lines

```
...    
<cfset RedOffset = (Start_Red - End_Red) / BoxNumber>
<cfset GreenOffset = (Start_Green - End_Green) / BoxNumber>
<cfset BlueOffset = (Start_Blue - End_Blue) / BoxNumber>

<div id="color-band">
<cfloop index="i" from="0" to ="#BoxNumber#">
    <cfset Red = int(Start_Red - (RedOffset * i))>
    <cfset Green = int(Start_Green - (GreenOffset * i))>
    <cfset Blue = int(Start_Blue - (BlueOffset * i))>
    <cfoutput>
    <div style="height: 5px; background-color:rgb(#Red#, #Green#, #Blue#)">&nbsp;</div>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

My apologies if this is not the direction you need to head but is there any reason you would not just create a single DIV with a gradient background (versus "x" number of divs with a solid background)? I understand if that's the case but thought I'd offer up the alternative in terms of CSS3 gradients. Otherwise, it seems as though Leigh's suggestion would work.

For this example, I went with your code as it looks like you wanted a red (255,0,0) to blue (0,0,255) gradient. I tweaked the code and ran it in Safari (5.1.5), Chrome (19.x) and FireFox (12):

```
<cfset Start_Red = 255 >
<cfset End_Blue = 255 >
<html>
    <cfoutput>
    <head>
        <title>Color Gradient Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .my_gradient{
                background: ##ff0000;
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(#Start_Red#, 0, 0) 0%, rgb(0,0,#End_Blue#) 100%); 
                background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(#Start_Red#, 0, 0)), to(rgb(0,0, #End_Blue#)) );"
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="color-band">       
        <div class="my_gradient">&nbsp;</div>       
        </div>
    </body>
    </cfoutput>
</html>
```

The above only creates a red (255,0,0) to blue (0,0,255) gradient in the aforementioned browsers, but [ColorZilla.com](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor) has a nice CSS Gradient Generator in that it generates the CSS you would need to use to get gradient effects across browsers.

Comment: +1. Yep, I much prefer that over reinventing the wheel (unless there is a specific reason they must do it manually. I was not sure about the goal)

Comment: I wasn't sure either, Leigh. I thought maybe the OP has some browser compat issues that were left unspoken. I figured between our two approaches, he'd get there :)!

Comment: This was a fine answer just not how i was trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your answer, but I do have two little suggestions.

1) Put your CFOUTPUTs around a larger block to make it more readable:

```
<cfoutput>
    <div style="background-color:rgb(#Red#, #Green#, #Blue#)">&nbsp;</div>
</cfoutput>
```

2) I use Hostek.com for ColdFusion hosting. They have awesome accounts for as little as $5 per month.  You can get CF8/9/10.  It's a great way to test out ColdFusion stuff cheaply.

Comment: or try http://www.hostmediauk.com.  They have free Railo accounts and a very cheap setup fee.  They also have cheap CF services.